# Disable flash in background when clicking CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

I have noticed that when you click on a CheckBox or a RadioButton in Android, the layout of the widget becomes white for a few milliseconds. How do you disable that ?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps use a different theme?

Comment: yes of course, or even put white background that will probably work, but if i want to keep a dark background ?